# Are any of these terms correct? "Known with" or "known by"

Tags: prepositions

Suppose a famous building, i.e. a stadium, a concert hall, etc., known as a landmark in a place, being sponsored by a company, such that people may happen to use the company name instead of the building name itself to refer to it.

How is it correct to talk about this?

> The building A is known *with* X.

or

> The building A is known *by* X.

I know there are terms like *known as*, and *known for*, but none of them suit this situation.

LDOCE and OxfordDictionaries don't mention anything with either of *by* or *with*, and Google NGram Viewer says:

[image]

Google search with double quotes has less than 1 million results for the former, but over 6 million for the latter. However not all of those results have the same meaning as this one, and I wonder how this can be expressed appropriately without sounding odd.

Comment: The only thing known with complete certainty is that only *known as* will suit the purpose you have set for it.

Comment: You can use *by*, but you need to put something else in there. "...known by *the term* X" or "...known by *its original name* X" or "...known by *the symbol* X". You can also leave out X in many cases " ...known by its owner's name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you say “known as” does not suit the situation? Seems natural to me.

And just looking for names of sports stadiums that are now referred to by their corporate names gives this example at Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_of_America_Stadium):

> The stadium, originally known as Carolinas Stadium . . . received its
>   current name after Bank of America purchased the naming rights . . .
>   many fans now refer to the stadium as, "The Bank", "The BOA", or
>   "BOFA"

Fans referring to the stadium as "The BOA” implies the stadium being also known as "The BOA.”